# Compare multiple Object/array based on array selection and output one object that includes all the matching array selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js, next.js13

selection = ["A", "lv3", "large"]

```
Data = [{ 
 id:1, title:"this is test 1", category:"A, D", level:"lv5", size: " 
 medium", }, 
 id:2, title:"this is test 1", category:"C", level:"lv1", size: "large", 
 },
 id:3, title:"this is test 1", category:"A, C", level:"lv3", size: " 
 medium, large", },
 id:4, title:"this is test 1", category:"B", level:"lv3, lv6", size: " 
 small", },
 id:5, title:"this is test 1", category:"B", level:"lv3", size: "large",
}]
```

The above is a sample data

output should be one "Data" object that only include the entries in the array "selection" that found in category, level and size.

I have tried the below however only works with one object at a time

```
const [courseData, setCourseData] = useState(Data);
const [updatedCourseData, setUpdatedCourseData] = useState(courseData);

  const combleveleresult =
      Data &&
      Data.filter((data: any) => {
      const level = selection.includes(data.level.toLowerCase());
      return level;
  });

  const combcategoryeresult =
      Data &&
      Data.filter((data: any) => {
      const category = selection.includes(data.category.toLowerCase());
      return category ;
   });

   const combsizeeresult =
        Data &&
        Data.filter((data: any) => {
        const size= selection.includes(data.size.toLowerCase());
        return size;
    });


    setUpdatedCourseData(combleveleresult )
```

Also tried the below, but same issue, only works on object at a time

```
const combine resultresult =
    courseData &&
    courseData.filter((data: any) => {
    const type = (data.type.toLowerCase().includes(selection) 
    || data.category.toLowerCase().includes(selection) || 
    data.level.toLowerCase().includes(selection));
    return type;
});

setUpdatedCourseData(resultresult)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const selection = ["A", "C", "lv3", "large"]

const data = [
{id:1, title:"this is test 1", category:"A, D", level:"lv5", size: "medium" },
{id:2, title:"this is test 2", category:"C", level:"lv1", size: "large" },
{id:3, title:"this is test 3", category:"A, C", level:"lv3", size: "medium, large" },
{id:4, title:"this is test 4", category:"B", level:"lv3, lv6", size: "small" },
{id:5, title:"this is test 5", category:"B", level:"lv3", size: "large"}]

console.log(data.filter(e=>selection.every(s=>
  ['category','level','size'].flatMap(j=>e[j].toLowerCase().split(', '))
    .includes(s.toLowerCase()))))
```

Comment: if I add another item in the selection as below it does not work.
Seem to work only with three item in selection. 

     const selection = ["A", "C", "lv3", "large"]

I should be getting below instead I get empty result []
     {id:3, title:"this is test 3", category:"A, C", level:"lv3",      size: "medium, large" },

Comment: @sdqworm it will now allow multiple matches